# Is asking an AI to illustrate Torah scenes a problem, if it might try to draw Hashem?

Tags: halacha, artificial-lifeform

I am a software developer and I've been experimenting with a variety of artificial intelligence that draws a picture based on a piece of provided text. (More specifically, I'm using VQGAN/CLIP and it provides TWO illustrations per prompt.) I've been providing it with verses of Torah.

I recently provided it with [Bereshit 19:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0). (in English, with Sefaria's translation, which just says "LORD")

I got back two AI-drawn images, one of which included a sort of impressionistic, partial face that I interpret to *maybe* be a drawing of Hashem. (The other of the two images is clearly fine.) The face looks kind of like Mr. T, but without anything above the forehead.

**Was this avodah zarah?** (Or whatever we call the rule against making idols.)

If it was, should I delete the image? Should I just be glad Yom K is coming up?

Comment: What makes something a drawing of Hashem, if Hashem has no image?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yeremiyahu and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This is both a good and bad question. AI is not defined in Judaism at all, so no inference can be made of it. On the other hand, maybe it is worth defining and dealing with it. I will try to ask a simpler question to help you out.

Comment: It's a good question, robev, what makes it a drawing of Hashem? The text describes Hashem raining fire on Sodom and Gemorrah, with Hashem the only actor. It seems like a reasonable inference that the big face in the image might be the one acting (although, to your point, I could interpret it to be a suffering resident of Sodom or Gemorrah and then there's no problem.)

Comment: The question may be similar to this if you ignore issues that can only be related to humans: If you ask someone with no or very little knowledge of Torah and who is not obligated in Torah such as a child to draw a picture of Hashem, would it be permitted? If this is considered a sin, then asking the AI to draw a Torah scene would probably be forbidden since you would be making a situation where there is a high probability of sinning.

Comment: I'm curious about the technology. how does your program "know" what LORD means? does it pull refs from a dictionary? does it "understand" the concept of a creator and tried to draw HIM?

Comment: @yih613: It's a "model" that somebody else made. Basically they showed it a bunch of pictures with captions, so it learned to equate words (from captions) with pictures. Then you can give it a new caption and it tries to come up with a picture that matches your caption. I don't think it has any sense of "concepts", but maybe.

Comment: In that case if it  was pics with the word lord in the caption (and the pics were actual avodah zarah) then I would hear the שאלה, cuz the software basically tried to redraw the parts of those pictures that it associated with the word lord i.e. the reason why the originals were ע"ז, otherwise I would be shocked if it were even a ספק אבוזריהו, I'm not a posek though....

Comment: @yih613 Ah, but that's interesting because I have no way to know what pics went into it (or to know which pics went into it with a caption that suggested it's Hashem, as opposed to Buddha or Thor or something). But I get your point and thank you for the discussion!